# Access list and interface vlan

Tags: vlan, acl, network-access

Pleasae I am facing this problem, the ping is always successful from 10.16.13.2 to 192.168.0.3

even if Iam configuring the acl in the 'in indirection'.

```
show ip access-list

  Extended IP access list wifi

  10 deny ip 10.16.13.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255

  20 permit ip any any (2 matches)

sh int vlan 13

 interface Vlan13

 ip address 10.16.13.254 255.255.255.0

 ip access-group wifi in
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the denied traffic is running through VLAN 13? Have you tried applying the ACL to the interface facing the WAP?

Comment: Yes, I am applying the acl to int vlan 13 as shown and have also specified the exact subnet for this vlan *10.16.13.0* in the acl.

Comment: When you run the ping does the number of matches in "permit ip any any" increase? If not, then this ACL doesn't apply to this traffic

Comment: yes,exactly it increases in the permit ip any any

Comment: Extended IP access list wifi
                                                                                                                                     
   10 deny ip 10.16.13.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                        
    20 permit ip any any (6 matches)

Comment: Can you try adjusting the deny statement in your access-list to something like below and testing? 10 deny icmp 10.16.13.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255

Comment: same thing the ping is seccfull , and the number of matches in "permit ip any any" increases ;                                                                                                                    Extended IP access list wifi
    10 deny icmp 10.16.13.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
    20 permit ip any any (2 matches)

Comment: Since the counter on ACL line 10 is not increasing, it's likely that the IP addresses are not as you're describing it.  Please edit your configuration to include the full device configurations as well as a simple diagram showing how they are connected.  The ACL matches your requirement.  Since it isn't working, either your addresses are wrong (most likely), or there's another misconfiguration.

Comment: I can confirm that the ACL is functioning as expected. Initially, I attempted to ping from the IP address of the Interface VLAN 13 (the gatway of this vlan 13) which means the ping was generated directly from the multilayer switch. However, I realized that the ACL's purpose is to filter traffic that passes through it, not the traffic generated by the device itself. This explains why the pings were not affected by the ACL. Thank you for your help and support.

Comment: You should write an answer for your own question so that others can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the ACL is functioning as expected. Initially, I attempted to ping from the IP address of the Interface VLAN 13 (the gatway of this vlan 13) which means the ping was generated directly from the multilayer switch. However, I realized that the ACL's purpose is to filter traffic that passes through it, not the traffic generated by the device itself. This explains why the pings were not affected by the ACL. Thank you for your help and support.